# how to add a comment feature to a listview

Tags: android, database, listview

I have an app under development in which there is a listview with a custom list adapter. I wanted to add a comment feature to every listview item.
This is the listview adapted used.

```
 public class FeedListAdapter extends BaseAdapter { 
    private Activity activity;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private List<FeedItem> feedItems;
    ImageLoader imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();

    public FeedListAdapter(Activity activity, List<FeedItem> feedItems) {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.feedItems = feedItems;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return feedItems.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int location) {
        return feedItems.get(location);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (inflater == null)
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (convertView == null)
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.feed_item, null);

        if (imageLoader == null)
            imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();

        TextView name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
        TextView timestamp = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.timestamp);
        TextView statusMsg = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.txtStatusMsg);
        TextView url = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtUrl);
        NetworkImageView profilePic = (NetworkImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.profilePic);
        FeedImageView feedImageView = (FeedImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.feedImage1);

        FeedItem item = feedItems.get(position);

        name.setText(item.getName());

        // Converting timestamp into x ago format
        CharSequence timeAgo = DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(
                Long.parseLong(item.getTimeStamp()),
                System.currentTimeMillis(), DateUtils.SECOND_IN_MILLIS);
        timestamp.setText(timeAgo);

        // Chcek for empty status message
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(item.getStatus())) {
            statusMsg.setText(item.getStatus());
            statusMsg.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            // status is empty, remove from view
            statusMsg.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        // Checking for null feed url
        if (item.getUrl() != null) {
            url.setText(Html.fromHtml("<a href=\"" + item.getUrl() + "\">"
                    + item.getUrl() + "</a> "));

            // Making url clickable
            url.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
            url.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            // url is null, remove from the view
            url.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        // user profile pic
        profilePic.setImageUrl(item.getProfilePic(), imageLoader);

        // Feed image
        if (item.getImge() != null) {
            feedImageView.setImageUrl(item.getImge(), imageLoader);
            feedImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            feedImageView
                    .setResponseObserver(new FeedImageView.ResponseObserver() {
                        @Override
                        public void onError() {
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess() {
                        }
                    });
        } else {
            feedImageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Should I create a multi level listview.
And I also wanted to know that after adding the comment feature to every listview is there a need to create a separate table in the database for each listview item for storing the different comments added, or else is there a different approach for this.And also help me knowing how to create a listview inside each listview item.

thank you.

Comment: @Heyyou yaa....each item should display list of comments entered when a listitem is selected..

Comment: @Heyyou okie....thanks a lot...

Answer (score 0):

I would not do such design personally, it will not be easy for users to find what they want easily in such screen. Instead you can open another screen to show comments on list item click. Or something like facebook's, you show comments count, when user clicks you open comment list in popup screen.

2 tables will be enough for comments as like below:

ListItem:

```
id   |  name
------------------
1    |  apple
2    |  banana
3    |  orange
```

ItemComment

```
id  |itemId   |  name
-------------------------------
1   |1        |  apple is good
2   |1        |  i love apple
3   |2        |  banana is yellow
```